# Communicating with Shell from Android Device

Tags: android, http, shell, connection, netcat

I want to send and receive messages between my Android phone and a Terminal shell. How can I do this?

I was thinking on the terminal I would just listen on a port with netcat then from the Android device I would somehow have to configure the IP address and port of my Terminal, I'm just not sure how to do that. Is it similar to making an HTTP Connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming by communicate you mean something like an insecure "chat" get a tcp client or server example in java, put device on same wifi as pc, and go with your netcat idea.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make a shell connection from your Android phone you can use [connectbot](http://code.google.com/p/connectbot/).

Works pretty well.